# If Couchbase key size is greater than RAM quota, how can i move some keys from RAM to disk

Tags: couchbase, bucket

for example; i have a huge data want to save in a bucket, all keys's size is 4G ,and the bucket's RAM quota is 3G, now can i save the huge data in the bucket,  is there have some method that some keys did not fit in RAM will overflow to disk, and how can i do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible (as of Couchbase 2.5.1). Currently, metadata (including the key) *has* to be held in RAM, to allow client requests to be able to quickly determine if a key exists.

Therefore in your example you wouldn't be able to store more than 3GB of keys (the bucket quota). Note even then you'd have no RAM left for actual document values, as they would always have to be read from disk.